# Probability equations

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, logic, propositional-calculus

I need to proof that

$$P[\varphi] \le P[\psi]\text{ does not imply }P[\varphi\rightarrow\psi] = 1 $$

$$P[\psi] + \varepsilon ≥ P[\varphi]\text{ does not imply }P[\varphi\rightarrow\psi] \ge 1− \varepsilon$$

$$P[\varphi] = P[\psi]\text{ does not imply }P[\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi] = 1 $$

I have the following information

$$
\operatorname{Pr}[\varphi]=\sum_{\beta \in Q,\ \beta | \models \varphi} p(\beta)
$$

Any advice?

Actual state:

For the first I have at the moment

$$P(A) = P(B)$$

$$P(A|B) = P(B|A)$$

$$\frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(A)}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have proved the other side that does hold

Comment: actually i'm researching formulas to proof this one

Comment: Letting $\psi$ be the negation of $\phi$ takes care of the first and third questions.

Comment: and how to i write that? The problem is that i don't know how to rewrite the formulas due to the fact that i have no formulas that are equivalent to P[φ→ψ] or P[φ↔ψ]

Comment: i have no clue how to proceed that

Comment: could someone tell me a keyword for that topic?